# Exporting To Azure SQL from Local SQL Database Failure

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, azure-sql-database

I have a local SQL Server 2012 database that used to export tables and views to Azure SQL daily. It's been working flawlessly for 3 months.

The export tasks were created by the SQL Server Studio Import/Export Wizard. They were saved into a SQL Server SSIS package and ran daily by a SQL Server Job.

Issue I am having:

For the past few months, the export process have been failing randomly with multiple errors. It mentions that the connection has dropped. I don't think this is the problem.

I can run `SELECT` statements against the Azure database in SSMS with no problem. The Azure database is read by Microsoft Power BI with no problem too. So I think the problem is local to my network.

> Executed as user: **HIDDEN**.
>   Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 11.0.2100.60 for 64-bit
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>   Started:  10:43:37
>   Error: 2016-07-05 10:43:37.84
>   Code: 0xC0016016
>   Source: Azure - Table - INV1
>   Description: Failed to decrypt protected XML node
>   "DTS:Password" with error 0x8009000B "Key not valid for use in
>   specified state.". You may not be authorized to access this
>   information. This error occurs when there is a cryptographic error.
>   Verify that the correct key is available.  End Error  Error:
>   2016-07-05 10:45:05.82     Code: 0xC0202009     Source: Data Flow Task
>   1 Destination - INV1 [2]     Description: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code:
>   0x80004005.  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft OLE DB
>   Provider for SQL Server"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description:
>   "[DBNETLIB][ConnectionWrite (send()).]General network error. Check
>   your network documentation.".  End Error  Error: 2016-07-05
>   10:45:05.82     Code: 0xC0209029     Source: Data Flow Task 1
>   Destination - INV1 [2]     Description: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Destination -
>   INV1.Inputs[Destination Input]" failed because error code 0xC020907B
>   occurred, and the error row disposition on "Destination -
>   INV1.Inputs[Destination Input]" specifies failure on error. An error
>   occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There
>   may be error messages posted before this with more information about
>   the failure.  End Error  Error: 2016-07-05 10:45:05.82     Code:
>   0xC0047022     Source: Data Flow Task 1 SSIS.Pipeline     Description:
>   SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on
>   component "Destination - INV1" (2) failed with error code 0xC0209029
>   while processing input "Destination Input" (15). The identified
>   component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is
>   specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the
>   Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted
>   before this with more information about the failure.  End Error 
>   Error: 2016-07-05 10:45:05.82     Code: 0xC02020C4     Source: Data
>   Flow Task 1 Source - INV1 [97]     Description: The attempt to add a
>   row to the Data Flow task buffer failed with error code 0xC0047020. 
>   End Error  Error: 2016-07-05 10:45:05.82     Code: 0xC0047038
>   Source: Data Flow Task 1 SSIS.Pipeline     Description: SSIS Error
>   Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Source - INV1
>   returned error code 0xC02020C4.  The component returned a failure code
>   when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the
>   failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and
>   the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted
>   before this with more information about the failure.  End Error 
>   DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started: 
>   10:43:37  Finished: 10:45:05  Elapsed:  88.156 seconds.  The package
>   execution failed.

Sometimes it works fine, other times it fails. I've noticed that smaller tables export fine, but larger ones like the error above have about 12,000 records. It fails randomly in different amount of records.

Has anyone any experience with what is going on?

Thanks!

Comment: Any chance that the error is correct `]General network error. Check your network documentation.".` and you actually have a connectivity issue?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I honestly don't think there is a problem. This is a production server and has no other issues other than the above. Having said that, I am open to the idea that it could be telling the truth. It has pending updates to install along with SQL 2012 SP3.

Comment: So I tried exporting on another SQL 2012 test server and that too failed. Same error as the above. It has to be either my internet connection or the Azure SQL Server.

Comment: Hi,I am getting the same error when using an intermediate SSIS server to load data from one Azure SQL to another Azure SQL. did anyone find anything?